# How to get joining class of a unicode character?

Tags: c++, c, text, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to find "the joining type" of a given char in unicode standard. The character is UTF8-encoded.

The joining class is a property that affects how a character (in Arabic script) is rendered by font. There are two types: right joining character and dual joining. (And maybe an undefined type for non-Arabic characters[?])

The question is not related to any specific programming language. If matters, I'm using C and C++.

PS: Notes on joining type can be found at [w3c.github.io/alreq/](https://w3c.github.io/alreq/#h_joining_behavior_of_characters)

Comment: A little google sent me to: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/based/U+0645.

Comment: There isn't a mechanism in standard C (or in POSIX) to find that out.  You'll need to review the facilities available in the Unicode library you're using.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not using a library.

Comment: OK. Then you'll need to either get one or write one for yourself, based on the information available from http://Unicode.org or similar places. Maybe the [ICU project](http://ICU-project.org) is appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

For reference: Unicode Character Database contains such information in `ucd/ArabicShaping.txt` accessible from this URL:

http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/ArabicShaping.txt